# Equivalent of dplyr::mutate for lists

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a list that contains multiple data frames. I want to go into each data frame within the list, perform an operation that will generate a new list for each row in the data frames, and then add a new column to each data frame containing the new lists.

Here is a toy example. I start with `ls_original`:

```
ls_original <- list(
    a = data.frame(id = 1:2, name = c("Jon", "Mark")), 
    b = data.frame(id = 3:6, name = c("Matt", "Marc", "Luke", "John"))
)
```

and am trying to generate `ls_desired`:

```
ls_desired <- list(
    a = data.frame(
        id = 1:2, 
        name = c("Jon", "Mark"), 
        lets = I(list(letters[1:1], letters[1:2]))
    ), 
    b = data.frame(
        id = 3:6, 
        name = c("Matt", "Marc", "Luke", "John"), 
        lets = I(list(letters[1:3], letters[1:4], letters[1:5], letters[1:6]))
    )
)
```

I would like to write a function that converts `ls_original` to `ls_desired`:

```
ls_desired <- list_mutate_function(ls_original)
```

I've tried the functions below. They give the new data that needs to be added to `ls_original` to generate `ls_desired`, but I can't figure out how to combine `ls_failed` with `ls_original` to generate `ls_desired`.

```
ls_failed1 <- ls_original %>% 
    lapply(function(x) {
        apply(x, 1, function(y) {
            letters[1:y[["id"]]]
        })
    })
ls_failed1

library(plyr)
ls_failed2 <- ls_original %>% 
    plyr::llply(function(x) {
        apply(x, 1, function(y) {
            letters[1:y[["id"]]]
        })
    })
ls_failed2
```

I also tried `lplyr::mutate` to no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested `map()` approach.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map(ls_original, ~mutate(.x, lets = map(id, ~letters[1:.x])))

$a
  id name lets
1  1  Jon    a
2  2 Mark a, b

$b
  id name             lets
1  3 Matt          a, b, c
2  4 Marc       a, b, c, d
3  5 Luke    a, b, c, d, e
4  6 John a, b, c, d, e, f
```